# How to get the SUM of values on a JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've got a 1-dimension JSONB on postgresql like this:

```
SELECT '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb;
```

**How to get the SUM of values on a JSONB column?
Like the sum of 1+2+3?**

PostgreSQL has the [jsonb_object_keys](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) function, but I was looking for something like *"jsonb_object_values"* (I know that this function does not exists)

```
# select jsonb_object_keys( '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb );
 jsonb_object_keys 
-------------------
 a
 b
 c
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jsonb_each_text()` function expands a set of JSON objects into rows in `(key, value)` format. Since it returns a set of rows, you should use it as a row source. Since it returns data in the `text` format, you should cast it to the appropriate type before further processing.

```
SELECT sum(v::integer)
FROM jsonb_each_text('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'::jsonb) j(k,v);
```